# wcf test client metadata error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcftestclient

I am a newbie in WCF and WCFTESTCLIENT.
I have a project on my desktop PC.It is written by c# and ASP.net MVC and is the core of a multimedia (.MP4 and .MP3) project.(IIS is installed).

and it should provide our android application with required stream of audio and video.

When I run WCF in VS2015 I encounter the below error and only I have a white page as output!

error in WCF Test Client:

1- "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata. "

2- Also when I run (F5) only I have a blank URL page without any error .

Please let me know what the problem is and how I can solve it?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: That is not necessarily a problem. You don't need to publish metadata to actually use the service. And a WCF service generally has no UI so a white screen usually just means the service is running. But if there is a problem you haven't given near enough info for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your ServiceBehavior for your endpoint make to make sure that `httpGetEnabled` is set to true?

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="yourServiceBehaviorname">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />


    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: If this is not the issue please provide more details.